# Empty string vs '#' in href=""

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In the [Bootstrap CSS examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), all of the placeholder links have `href="#"`.

I understand that `href="#"` provides a `preventDefault()`-like behavior, but without JS. Is there any other reason to use `href="#"`?

And if you're `href="#"` in this manner, isn't it more "correct" to use a `<button>` instead?

Comment: Personally i would avoid `#` at all, it will cause a jump to the top of the page. Use `javascript:void(0)` It will work with and without javascript since it will do nothing in either cases

Comment: I recommend avoiding `href="#"` because browsers will scroll to the top if the default behavior isn't prevented, `href="javascript:;"` doesn't have that issue.

Comment: Your assumption that `href="#"` "provides a `preventDefault()`-like behavior" is incorrect. To avoid having the browser jump to the top of the document, you would still need to call `preventDefault()` on the event.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and pointing out the dupe! I was looking but couldn't find. I will vote to close too.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href If it exists it have to be a valid URL

Comment: Miguel is correct - if you actually just want it to prevent default, and still feel like you need to include the href for some reason, the most correct implementation is `<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault()">An empty link!</a>` -- or take out the onclick and handle the event in separate js. Best general approach is, as in my answer below, to simply not specify an href, as that's now valid, and I don't believe that older browsers your users may have will have trouble with it (in spite of a missing href being invalid in html4)

Comment: If you want an empty `href`, that is a sure sign that you do not want to use an `<a>` element. Why would you use it when that is not what you need? Because it is blue and has an underline? Do you use `<h1>` because it gives you big bold text? Wrong. Use an element that is appropriate for your situation (maybe a `<button>` styled with CSS).

Comment: Right, @kapa that was the point of my question: since `<a href="#">` should be `<button>`, why would a very significant project like Bootstrap use this for all of its examples?

Comment: @dimadima Nobody is perfect. I see this mistake all the time, I think most sitebuilders simply never stopped to think that they should not use an `<a>` if they don't need a link. This topic about the empty `href` is discussed from time to time, and one solution is worse than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend MDN as a better resource for understanding HTML standards than the bootstrap examples. Bootstrap is often quite focused on mixing style into your HTML itself, and often shortcuts around the 'proper' way of doing things. That said, it's generally quite pretty and does a lot of things fast, and like anything in programming you can write good or bad code using it.

The 'href' attribute was a required attribute in previous HTML specs, so you would always need it. href="#" was a quick and dirty way of essentially omitting it. It's no longer required in the html5 spec, and  without an href is specifically used to create placeholder links, as described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: "without an href is specifically used to create placeholder links" It would actually be a hyperlink **target**.

Answer (score 0):

I like more w3c for those things, spite of MDN, (for standards I mean).

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href

If it exists, it has to be a valid URL – But it is not a required attribute.

Comment: An empty string is a valid URL according to the specs; see the other question this one's a duplicate of.